# Pandas Can not sum dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this.

```
                                  E   F                                 
    ID    A     B       C     D   E   F
    0    0     ABC    AAA    BCD  1   -
    1    1     ABC    AAA    BCD  4   -  
    2    2     ABC    AAA    BCD  6   -
```

I print type of dataframe by `print(type(df['E']))` it show output like this.

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I try to sum total value in column E but it show output like this

```
E146
```

How to sum data in dataframe column? The correct value should be 11 (1+4+6).

Comment: Use `df['E'][-3]` and sum. The sum function is not working properly on because of the single `E` character present in the column `E` of your dataframe. In that case it concatenates the values of the column which results in the output `E146`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
print(df['E'].iloc[1:].astype(int).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pd.to_numeric` with `coerce` to flip non-numeric value to `NaN` and sum will handle `NaN` by itself

```
pd.to_numeric(df['E'], errors='coerce').sum()

Out[45]: 11.0
```